# Control UI If any retrofit service is running

Tags: android, fragment, retrofit

I'm using `retroft` to download files from rest api, when user clicks on download `button`, the downloading process starts, and I show a `progressbar` and disable the `button`, the problem is that when user changes Activity or fragment and comes back to the download page, the download process is running in the background, but because the `onCreateView` of the `fragment` called again, the download button becomes enabled and the progress bar is not showing.

is there any way to control the UI, when `retrofit` is downloading the files?

thanks.

Comment: You can check status of download and decide to show progress. Isn't it?

Comment: you can use download manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Google latest recommendations, you should use LiveData and keep all downloading logic in fragments ViewModel and then on fragments onActivityCreated just bind progress and button to progress live data.

More here: 
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel 
And here: 
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata